# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS DBInstance via Hibernate or sqlplus

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created a DBInstance in RDS. I have added a VPC security group with a subnet including the machines IP from which I will be sending requests. However, I am not able to connect to the DBInstance yet. The connection times out. I am specifying the following details in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 </property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 </property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://{DBInstanceName}.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/{dbname}
 </property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
  {username}
 </property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
  {password}
 </property>
</session-factory>
```

I am out of ideas on what could be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

P.S: I also tried connecting using sqlplus but in vain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your AWS account, go to RDS, click on Security Groups.  Make sure your security group is set up properly to allow your IP address to connect to RDS (add a CIDR to the appropriate security group).

More information can be found here [Working with DB Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html)

Comment: In the supported platforms, it says only 'VPC' .. so I have to add a VPC security group .. when i click on the security group under RDS, it says I have to create a VPC security group. I have done that already but I will probably do it again with a clean slate. I just wanted to be sure if that itself is the problem.